# Bootstrap CSS, issue with navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Within a bootstrap navbar I want to input a logo and some text as header.

My code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="images/lzd_logo.png">Daily Newsletter Dashboard</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="menuTop active"><a href="#">TH</a></li>
                <li class="menuTop"><a href="#">MY</a></li>
                <li class="menuTop"><a href="#">ID</a></li>
                <li class="menuTop"><a href="#">SG</a></li>
                <li class="menuTop"><a href="#">VN</a></li>
                <li class="menuTop"><a href="#">PH</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="campaignDate" name="campaignDate" placeholder="Date" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5t2g5y8d/2/

I have two issues: 
**1)** How can I reduce the padding-top for the logo? (I don't mind the fact that the logo has a higher height than the navbar, I just want to reduce a little bit the padding-top). 
**2)** How can I display the text to the right side of the logo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following style to the css, hope this will solve your issue.

```
.navbar-brand{
    padding:5px 15px 0 15px;
}
.navbar-brand img{
    float:left;
}

.navbar-brand span{
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
}
```

updated **[fiddle file](https://jsfiddle.net/5t2g5y8d/9/)**

Comment: do this, and put a fixed width: on the .navbar-brand so the text can fit to the right

Comment: nice thanks a lot, but how can i give the original padding-top to the text? in order to align the text with the navbar menu?

Comment: @zedd please what do you mean by a fixed width?

Comment: to align the text you need to wrap the text with span, I have updated my answer.

Comment: you can adjust .navbar-brand span top postion as per your requirement.

Comment: not need to use important, I used important to over-right the bootstrap css in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5t2g5y8d/8/)**

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
    padding:0px;
}
.navbar-brand .logotxt, .navbar-brand img {
    display:inline-block;  
}
.navbar-brand .logotxt{  
    padding:15px 15px;
    vertical-align:top;       
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button pull-right" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> 
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button> <a class="navbar-brand pull-left">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ed/Small_logo_splash.png">
        <span class="logotxt">some text</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead and it will solve the issue:

Apply to fix the padding:

```
 .navbar-header .navbar-brand{
    padding:0px 15px 0 15px ;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

Use **line-height** to vertically align the text on the navbar.

**NEVER USE !important, USE SPECIFICITY TO OVERRIDE**(use more or higher selectors instead).

Also to directly display the text on the right side of the logo, on the navbar:

```
.navbar-header .navbar-brand>img {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Use **display:inline-block** in this case.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/5t2g5y8d/11/